# Validation of JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I want to validate the JSP in the JSP itself but it is givin me a nullpointer Exception..My code is given below...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="admincss/style.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<%
String username=request.getParameter("txt_username");
String password=request.getParameter("txt_password");
if(username.equals("k") && password.equals("k"))
{
    response.sendRedirect("Admin");
}
%>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
      <form method="post" action="admin.jsp">
        <p><input type="text" name="txt_username" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="txt_password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <p class="remember_me">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
            Remember me on this computer
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="btn_commit" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="login-help">
      <p>Forgot your password? <a href="index.html">Click here to reset it</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="about">
    <p class="about-links">
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/login-form" target="_parent">View Article</a>
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/login-form.zip" target="_parent">Download</a>
    </p>
    <p class="about-author">
      &copy; 2012&ndash;2013 <a href="http://thibaut.me" target="_blank">Thibaut Courouble</a> -
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/mit-license" target="_blank">MIT License</a><br>
      Original PSD by <a href="http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/clean-simple-login-form-psd/" target="_blank">Orman Clark</a>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand the error.....If this is not the right method please suggest me the right one

Answer (score 0):

`NullPointerException` generally means you tried to call a method or access a field on a variable doesn't refer to any object.  The only variables you're using in this file, aside from the predefined `request` and `response`, are `username` and `password`.

The `request.getParameter` method returns `null` if the request doesn't have a parameter with the specified name.  So if your request doesn't include a `txt_username` and/or `txt_password` parameter, the `username` and/or `password` variable will be null.

On the line below, when you call `username.equals` and `password.equals`, you'll get the exception if those variables are null.  You can't call the method if there's no object to call it on.

You need to add some code to handle the case where `username` or `password` are null.